# Does there exist an uncountable measure zero subset of R^n which is a dense first category set

Tags: algebraic-topology

Does there exist an uncountable measure zero subset of $\mathbb R^n$ which is a dense first category set, $F_\sigma$ but not $G_\delta$?

Comment: I have rudimentary ideas which aren't enough to solve this one. But this excites me somehow.

Comment: Have you tried something for small $n$, say $n=1$?

Comment: To begin with, can you think of an uncountable nowhere dense closed subset of the real line, whose Lebesgue measure is zero?

Comment: Actually, I've found it easier to think of an example in $\mathbb{R}^2$, if it's any help.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Cantor set?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Can you give the example in R² if there?

Comment: @Epsilonzero: Yes, the standard Cantor set $C$ will do the job. Can you think now of a countable union of rescaled copies of $C$ such that the union is dense in the real line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the set $\mathcal{F}\subset\mathbb R^2$ given by

$$\mathcal{F}=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\,|\, y=0 \lor \frac{x}y\in\mathbb{Q}\right\}$$

For $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, let $r_\alpha = \{(\alpha\,y,y)\,|\, y \in \mathbb R\}$, and observe that $r_\alpha\subset \mathbb R^2$ is always closed.
We can write

$$\mathcal{F}=\{(x,0)\,|\,x\in\mathbb R\}\cup \bigcup_{q\in\mathbb Q}r_q,$$

which is a countable union of closed sets, so that $\mathcal{F}$ is $F_\sigma$.
It's easy to see that $\mathcal{F}$ is uncountable and dense.
Moreover, it has measure $0$ because it is the countable union of measure $0$ sets.

> **Claim:** $\mathcal{F}$ is not $G_\delta$.

*Proof:* Let $\mathcal{G}=\mathbb R^2\setminus\mathcal{F}$.
If $\mathcal{F}$ were $G_\delta$, then $\mathcal{G}$ would be $F_\sigma$, so we could write $\mathcal{G}$ as some countable union $\cup_{i}\,G_i$ of closed sets $G_i$.

Then, we could write $\mathbb{R}^2$ as

$$\underbrace{\{(x,0)\,|\,x\in\mathbb R\}\cup \left(\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb Q}r_q\right)}_\mathcal{F}\cup\underbrace{\left(\bigcup_i G_i\right)}_\mathcal{G},$$

a countable union of closed sets.
By Baire's Category Theorem, it follows that at least one of these sets has non-empty  interior.
Here we arrive at a contradiction, for both $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ have empty interior. $\square$